# Copy a 4 dimensionnal array to another list

Tags: python, list

is there a way I can copy a 4 dimensionnal array without using any outer method?

I have this two dimensionnal array copy,
its i french sorry

```py
def copie_profonde_liste(liste): # Fonction qui permet de copier une liste sur deux dimensions
    """
    Entrée : une variable de type liste
    Sortie : une variable de type liste dans laquelle on a copié la liste d'entrée de deux dimensions
    """
    copie_liste = [] # On initialise la copie de la liste
    for liste_a_trois_obj in liste: # Pour chaque liste de trois objets dans la longueur de la liste d'entree
        copy_of_liste_a_trois_obj = [] # On initialise une liste vide pour copier chaque element (la deuxieme dimension)
        for single_value in liste_a_trois_obj: # Pour chaque element de la liste de trois objets
            copy_of_liste_a_trois_obj.append(single_value) # On copie l'element dans la liste vide
        copie_liste.append(copy_of_liste_a_trois_obj) # On ajoute la liste de trois objets copie dans la liste vide
    return copie_liste # On retourne la liste copiee
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use 'copy' on a list.
Here's example:

```py
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [1, [0, 1]], 0, 1]  # DEFINE AN ARRAY
print(arr)  # PRINT THIS ARRAY
arr_copy = arr.copy()  # COPY THIS ARRAY TO arr_copy
print(arr_copy)  # PRINT THE arr_copy
```

This code should work for every array (2d, 3d, etc.).